# Docker и /etc/hosts

Tags: docker, lamp, docker-compose

Не могу раздуплиться с докером. Листаю рецепты настройки LAMP через docker контейнеры. В большинстве случаев домены прописываются непосредственно в /etc/hosts на хост машине вида

```
127.0.0.1 somehost.dev
```

Неужели нужно редактировать руками файл /etc/hosts на хост машине, чтобы увидеть домены из /etc/hosts контейнера с вебсервером?

Comment: Не уверен что правильно понял, но можно при создании контейнера через Dockerfile указать `COPY hosts /etc/` , то есть не обязательно использовать именно системный hosts + можно монтировать его через `-v`

Comment: это плохая идея. очень, очень плохая идея

Comment: тебе надо каждый вебсервер на разных портах открыть  и ссылаться имямашины:порт

Comment: опишите задачу, а не решение. чем не подходит готовое решение? зачем делаете свое?

Comment: Контейнер с вебсервером эти домены не увидит. Забегая вперед - файл /etc/hosts внутри контейнера управляется самим докером, и переписать его в докерфайле не получится.